# Sql - Grouping data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Site Table

WBSNumber | SiteCode | ASNumber | SiteName

1..........................11112...........1.................SiteA

1....................... .          11112 ..........    2...............       SiteA

2.........................          42342..........     2...............       SiteB

2.........................           42342..........      1...............         SiteB

2.........................           42342..........      3...............         SiteB

3.........................           78965..........      1...............         SiteC

4.........................           78954..........      1...............        SiteD

5.........................           112233..........     1...............        SiteE

5.........................           112233..........     2...............        SiteE

I'm struggling to write some sql that will return a list of all the sites, with a unique WBSNumber based on the highest ASNumber.

So in my case, i'm expecting the following results back:

WBSNumber | SiteCode | ASNumber | SiteName

1....................... .          11112 ..........    2...............       SiteA

2.........................           42342..........      3...............         SiteB

3.........................           78965..........      1...............         SiteC

4.........................           78954..........      1...............        SiteD

5.........................           112233..........     2...............        SiteE

Here WBSNumber is unique and only select the rows based on the highest ASNUmber.

Comment: Can you please format this better and make it more obvious what your question is?

Comment: Also show us what you have tried thus far

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT WBSNumber, SiteCode, MAX(ASNumber) ASNumber, SiteName
 FROM SiteTable
GROUP BY WBSNumber, SiteCode, SiteName
```

`MAX` is used to get highest ASNumber, and other columns must be included in `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MAX(ASNumber) as 'ASNumber'` or `MAX(ASNumber) 'ASNumber'` instead of `MAX(ASNumber) ASNumber` ?

Comment: `as` is not required, nor are the apostrophe's/single quotes.   Perfectly valid solution as it is. provided  siteCode and SiteName are always the same for a given WBSNumber.

Comment: You don't need to use quotation marks for alias in SQL Server, only if you have space in alias like 'AS Number'

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic to assign a rownumber (starting at 1 increasing by one)  to each wbsnumber for the highest ASnumber and then select the rownumber of 1...

```
with cte as 
(Select s.*, Row_number() over (partition by wbsNumber order by asNumber desc) RN)
Select * from cte 
where RN = 1
```

or prior to analytics...
We generate a set of data for max ASnumber for each WBSNumber and simply allow an inner join to exclude all the other records.

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM Site S
INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(ASNumber) mASNumber, WBSNumber From site Group by WBSNumber) S2
 on S.WBSNumber = S2.WBSNumber
and S.ASNumber = S2.mASNumber
```

This approach ensures all other data in the table is preserved; so if you had a different SiteName for the higest ASNumber, we'd get only the name for the highest ASnumber.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, WBS, SiteCode and SiteName are all unique to each other. So you just need the max ASNnumber

```
select distinct
    WBSNumber,
    SiteCode,
    SiteName,
    Max(ASNumber) as ASNumber
from SiteTable
group by
    WBSNumber,
    SiteCode,
    SiteName
```

If that's not the case, you could just get the max WBS as well...

```
select distinct
    Max(WBSNumber) as WBSnumber,
    SiteCode,
    SiteName,
    Max(ASNumber) as ASNumber
from SiteTable
group by
    SiteCode,
    SiteName
```

Otherwise we need a larger data sample... or use `RowNumber()`